# document.body.clientHeight not working? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

document.body.clientHeight not returning correct values (in below code return 0 onload and 20 onresize )

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled</title>
<script type="text/javascript" >
function height1()
{
    document.getElementById("viewheight").innerHTML = document.body.clientHeight;
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="height1();" onresize="height1();">
<span id="viewheight"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Any Comments..... plz help!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try it with `document.getElementById("viewheight").innerHTML = window.innerHeight;`

The behaviour of your script is totally correct.
At the start the height of your body is really zero (body height is the height of the document). Because there's nothing shown, the height results with zero.
After resizing your printed "0" spans over 20px, so the result will stay at 20px.

If you want to get the maximum height of the window or the body you could use `Math.max( window.innerHeight, document.body.clientHeight )`

Comment: maybe some applied css stretched the body in your example book to another size, or there's more content in the page

Comment: Is `document.body.clientHeight` deprecated?

Comment: @Pranshu_23 Put this twice in your script and check the console: `console.log(document.getElementById("viewheight").innerHTML = document.body.clientHeight);`, you'll see the difference;

Comment: `window.innerHeight` is the visible portion of the page, `document.body.clientHeight` is the total page height. They are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

here is a **not clean solution** , but it cloud help someone else.

- solution is to give to the element **position,height**

```css
body{
    position: absolute; 
    height: 100%; /*any value*/
}
```

- then **clientHeight** will work

Answer (score -1):

`.clientHeight` gives us a Integer value only. But here scale-type of size is missing that's why it is not working correctly just add `+ "px"` just after `document.body.clientHeight`.

```
<script>
    function height1() {
        document.getElementById("viewheight").innerHTML = document.body.clientHeight + "px";
    }
</script>
```